# How to install deb files on kubuntu without using terminal?

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, discover-software-center

I just installed Kubuntu and downloaded chrome, steam, and Dropbox deb files. When I try to install them using Kubuntu's software manager *Discover*, it says it can not install from an unsigned repo.

Is there a way I can install deb files by double clicking them in Kubuntu without using dpkg from the terminal?

Comment: What leads you to want to do it this way? What's the problem with dpkg?

Comment: You may want to look into `gdebi`, which is a handy GUI method of installing software.

Comment: 'it says it can not install from an unsigned repo.' why do you assume any other method would not end up with the same problem? why not ask how to fix the problem instead of trying to circumvent it?

Comment: I am having the same issue - brand new Kubuntu 22.04 install. Downloaded Chome - now trying to install with QApt - It takes 20 seconds to respond and open a dialog. Then I click install and wait - NOTHING - no message or error. After 1 minute close down repeat - Why is it so difficult to install a file ???

Answer (score 1):

You can use either **apt** or **dpkg** to install deb files. With **apt** you can try `apt install <file>.deb` or with **dpkg** you can try `dpkg -i <file>.deb && apt install -f`. Of course you might need sudo privileges with either methods. A good explanation of these is given on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt).

If you still get errors about it being an unsigned repo, you can add `[trusted=yes]` in the sources.list file for the repo in question. But do so at your own discretion as it might expose you to bugs and security issues.

Comment: Just remember that you need to use the full path to the file when using apt. So if the deb file is in the current directory, you'd need to have ./ before the filename.

Comment: I am in my downloads folder with the chrome deb - when I run sudo apt install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb, it says its unable to locate the file. This is madness. I can see it in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu `qapt` should be installed by default.
So you could just right-click on your .deb and select open with QApt Package Installer, which is not as strict with unsigned repos as Discover. I wouldn't use Discover anyhow, because it gives you normally not enough feedback about dependencies, so I would go with `qapt` (or with apt in the CLI as mentioned above.)

If qapt ist not yet istalled, run `sudo apt-get install qapt-deb-installer`

hope that helps

Comment: QAPT does not work for me. Brand new install. It takes 20 seconds to open a dialog offering to install. Click the install button - nothing. 1 hour wasted already.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a different GUI installer. First, install GDebi Package Installer using your Discover software center app.

Next, open your Dolphin file manager and navigate to the deb file. Right-click on the deb file and then select "**Properties**".

On the "**General**" tab, click on "**File Type Options**".

Under "**Application Preference Order**", click on **GDebi Package Installer** and then click on "**^ Move Up**" until GDebi is at the top of the list.

Click "**OK**" to close the File Type Options window.

Click "**OK**" to close the Properties window.

Now, you can double click on a deb file and GDebi will open. You can install the package if you click on "**Install**".